# Prove that if the functional sequence ‎$xf(n) + \sum_{k=1}^n f(k)$ ‎is ‎convergent‎ ‎then the sequence ‎$‎f(n)$ ‎is ‎convergent

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let ‎$‎f:D_f‎\rightarrow‎\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $‎‎\mathbb{N}‎‎\subseteq D_f‎$. My question is proving or disprving the following\‎

"If the functional sequence ‎$xf(n) + \sum_{k=1}^n f(k)$ ‎is ‎convergent as ‎$‎‎n\to{‎\infty}‎$‎ ‎‎‎then the sequence ‎$‎‎f(n)$ ‎is ‎convergent." ‎(‎$‎‎x\in‎\mathbb{R}‎$‎)‎\

Note that, if the series ‎$‎\sum_{n=1}^{‎\infty‎} f(n)$ is convergent then getting the result is clear. So, we should find the other cases.
‎

Comment: @Thomas Andrews, yes thank you I edited it

Comment: It's not clear why there is an $x$ and an $n$ in this question. Can you be more precise about what this functional sequence is? Is it $g_n(x)$?

Comment: @Thomas Andrews, yes it is

Comment: @Thomas Andrews, for example if $f(x)=a^x$ then I mean that $g_n(x)=xa^n+\sum_{k=1}^na^n$, but it is simple. I want to know what happens in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g_n(x):=xf(n)+\sum_{k=1}^{n} f(n)$ then:

$$2g_n(x) - g_n(2x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} f(k)$$